# How to export dataset into the notepad with column Separator "/" and row separator "|" using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Need to store dataset data into the text file with column Separator "/"  and row separator "|" using asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the tables in the dataset and for each:

- Create a string builder,
- loop over all the rows,
- loop over columns in the rows.
- Write the data and column seperator to string except for last column
- Write the row seperator.

And you are done.

Call string builders `ToString()` method and you get the output.